# Set datatables ordering from request url

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to find a way to modify the initial ordering of a datatable when the request url or url parameter contains a certain value.

I'm calling data via ajax similar to this example: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

An request might be `https://test.local/office` or `https://test.local?col=office`

In which case I'd like the initial render of the data table to be ordered by `office` in descending.

I've read in to the datatables docs and can see how to set the order using an index value, but cannot see anything to indicate the how to use a string

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": [ 2, 'desc' ]
} );
```

Is there a way I can use a string to alter the ordering of the data, something similar to this?

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": [ 'office, 'desc' ]
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a named column ordering (instead of index).

As far I know, we can't order by name as stated on [this datatable forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28423/sorting-ordering-columns-using-column-name-data-class).

What I have come up with is:

```js
// Convert url query string to object. I'm using `query-string` library.
// e.g. convert `?order=office&dir=asc` to `{order: 'office', dir: 'asc'}`.
let urlParams = require('query-string').parse(window.location.search);

...


$('#example').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  order: [], // <-- initially empty to avoid defaulting to order: [[0,'asc']].
  columns: [
    ...
    { data: 'office', name: 'office' },
    ...
  ],
  ajax: {
    url: '...', // e.g. url+window.location.search
    data: function (data) {
      // Override the order and dir to be sent to server.
      // Set it to the currently clicked column, or default to what is present in the url parameter.
      let columnName = data.order.length ? data.columns[data.order[0].column].name : urlParams.order; // e.g. 'office'
      let dir = data.order.length ? data.order[0].dir : urlParams.dir;

      // Build the url query params.
      let params = {
        order: columnName, // send the column name 'office' to the server as `?order=office`.
        dir: dir,
        ...
      }

      // Refresh the window.location.search without reloading the browser.
      let urlQueryString = require('query-string').stringify(params);
      window.history.replaceState(null, null, '?'+urlQueryString);

      return params;
    }
  },
});
```

Few things to note:

- on your frontend, the url param will need to be declared in the browser. E.g. https://test.local/offices?order=office&sort=asc
- your ajax call will then need to append the url param found in the browser. E.g. https://test.local/api/v1/offices?order=office&sort=asc